# My Nikon D90 releases half shutter, how do I fix it?

Tags: shutter, nikon-d90, shutter-release

I have a Nikon D90 camera with DX lens. It started to give some trouble when taking pictures.

When I set a focus and press the button to take it, it makes a single sound, but does not take a picture. When I press it again, then it completes taking the picture, but the picture that is takes is half black.

I have uploaded the pictures at https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnRmp.jpg

I took it to a Camera shop(Nikon authorized shop) and they told me that the shutter is tilted and cannot be fixed. The Camera is gone and cannot be used further. They started giving me options to buy D3500 and D5600 telling me that they are on sale.

I have also uploaded the image of my camera shutter https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnRmp.jpg

Can someone please confirm if there are no hopes of getting my camera shutter fixed?

What are my options?

Thank you very much

Comment: Replacing the shutter on a D90 would cost several times what the camera is worth. Itr is time to move on.

Comment: Could "Tilted" also mean the part of the housing that the shutter attaches to is in itself warped and would destroy any replacement shutter in short order?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Attempt to disassemble and rebuilt the camera with the parts as is - Depending on whether anything has cracked/split/bent, this may be effectively impossible.

It is also very difficult if you are not extremely familiar with fabricating delicate electronic devices.

---

Option 2:

Buy a "parts camera" of the same model, but which suffered different damage [Such as one with a busted screen], take both apart, and reassemble a single working camera.

Again, a very difficult task if you're not familiar with working on such projects.

---

Option 3:

Sell current body as a parts camera, and buy a working replacement.

Minimal technical skill required... [Minor risk of getting scammed?] and is probably your most sensible option.

---

Option 4:

Buy film cameras with reliable leaf shutters, and enjoy life as a hipster or something?
[This option may or may not have been satirical in nature. Film is fun to work with, but is obviously not everyone's cup of tea, or suitable for all photography tasks.]

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be fixed, you just need to find a skilled repair shop that will go into detail work. The cost for part replacement and labor might be close to replacing your D90 with another or a similar model.